# Use httr to create POST call for Bearer token

Tags: r, json, post, httr

I am using R.

I am new to API's and trying to figure out how to put the post call together to get the required bearer token.
I am using the Experian Sandbox.

Once I have the bearer token i'm good but getting the Post call put together is proving to be very difficult for me.

+below was clipped from the developer portal.

> The call to get the Oauth2 token is a POST request with a Content-Type
>   which needs to be specified as JSON; the response will also be in JSON
>   format:

Request example:

```
curl -X POST
-d '{"username": "youremail@email.com", "password": "YOURPASSWORD"}'
-H "Client_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
-H "Client_secret: xxxxxxxxx"
-H "Cache-Control: no-cache"
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
"https://sandbox-us-api.experian.com/oauth2/v1/token"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following solution took care of my issue should anyone else need it for future reference.  Thank you to R Community on helping to get me up to date on how this call is performed.

```
post_req <- httr::POST(
  "https://sandbox-us-api.experian.com/oauth2/v1/token",
  add_headers(
    "Content-Type" = "application/json", 
    "Cache-Control"="no-cache",
    "Client_secret"="xxxxxxxxxx",
    "Client_id"="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
  body = '{"username": "youremail@email.com", "password": "YOURPASSWORD"}',
  verbose()
)
```